# When typing a custom rejection reason, the Enter key should submit the edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, usability, keyboard

When I am rejecting a suggested edit, I like to use the "custom" box to give more directed feedback to would-be editors. But there's a usability problem there that disrupts my workflow.

After I've finished typing and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, I expect the form to be automatically submitted just as if I'd moved my mouse down to click the "Reject" button.

Instead, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key currently returns to a new line, which is useless considering that the suggested edit rejection reasons don't show line breaks.

[image: Line breaks within custom edit rejection reason]

I realize that the standard behavior of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is to insert a new line, but having it trigger a submission for something that doesn't support multiple paragraphs is not unprecedented. We do precisely this for the comment box already. You have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in order to return to the next line. The "custom" field in the suggested edit rejection dialog should work the same way.

Comment: The custom close reason dialog [has the same issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222489/when-entering-custom-close-reason-controlreturn-doesnt-submit-vote).