# Press Return in Other reason

Tags: feature-request, close-dialog

Why can't I submit a close vote with the "Other" reason by typing into the reason field and pressing Return? The reason otherwise seems like a comment prompt box, but Return just goes to the next line. Which is useless, since there's no formatting in comments.

Comment: Strongly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133738/152859 (if they do one, they should do both and maybe there are more)