# When entering custom close reason, Control+Return doesn't submit vote

Tags: bug, keyboard-shortcuts, close-dialog

**Repro steps**:

1. Open the vote-to-close dialog.
2. Navigate to *Custom close reason*.
3. Type text.
4. Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>

**Current behaviour**: A wild newline appears!

**Expected behaviour**: The close vote is submitted.

**Rationale**: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> immediately applies edits when used while editing a question, answer or comment. It's confusing to deviate from that standard. (Plus it's a really nice shortcut. I miss it.)

The same [doesn't work in the edit rejection dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133738/when-typing-a-custom-rejection-reason-the-enter-key-should-submit-the-edit) either.

Comment: I didn't even know you could use Ctrl+Enter there -- learnt something new!

Comment: @Qa Discovered by happy accident. Also try Shift+Enter to automatically add the next element onto a bulleted or numbered list!